# What access does a browser in a macos standard account have into an admin account?

Tags: macos, user-account

Aloha!
I'm finding that more and more websites become partially or fully unusable when I use my 6-year old Mac, or have trackers/blockers/little snitch on.

So I'm thinking of having another account on the mac for 'dodgy' (that is, more or less 'everyday'...) onlining and using Google products, etc. But am still worried about content of my Admin account being taken, tracked, etc.

If I run a browser in a Standard or Sharing only account, can that browser and the filth I come across while using it see/take/track stuff in my Admin account, or is it fairly safe to use this technique to protect the Admin material?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, a webpage cannot read and send 'content' from your user account (e.g. files, contacts, mail, etc) to an external server.  And normally, one user account should not be able to access the contents of another.

What tends to get tracked is linking your usage on one webpage with your use of another page. In the case of Google and Facebook, this is linked to your account.

Using Google search and mail in a separate user account doesn't provide any benefit of anonymity. If you're concerned about privacy, then you shouldn't use Googlemail **at all**.

MacOS offers very good protection against various forms of tracking.
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac

Keeping your OS up-to-date is the best way to stay secure on-line. Not updating leaves you vulnerable to known exploits, which have since been patched.

Comment: Hi Benwiggy, thanks for the quick and useful answer!
When you say 'normally...' how do you mean? It's possible but not likely depending on... if a user is out on many outlets and making themselves a target?
I don't use any 'social media' and feel dirty when going to Google products, which is part of why I want to contain such in a separate account.
The older Mac, I won't update. Period. I don't like where Apple products are going, and accept that it will eventually not be usable online, which makes it even safer for it to hold personal material.
I'll use a refurb for this activity.

Comment: @DaveN What do you mean by "Google products"? I used "normally", as there are always remote possibilities and methods for the user to make things worse. Not updating your Mac means it won't get the latest security fixes and improvements. As said, your personal material is not at risk from web browsing.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. I'm not too worried about the remote possibilities, more the everyday tracking, profiling etc and hoovering of contacts and so on. I haven't used any Apple 'improvements' in a while, and every update on every gadget I spend at least half an hour scouring settings and turning off stuff they changed or hid or added. Google products, like Search, Mail, all that. I only use Gmail or Voice on an isolated account/computer.

Comment: Thanks benwiggy, I got sidetracked in that last comment... to summarize, you're saying using a browser in either a Standard or Sharing Only account on Macos should not expose my files or online activity that occur in an Admin account on the same computer (except for remote possibilites etc)?

Comment: @DaveN Neither your Contacts, nor your files cannot be 'hoovered up' through web tracking. I think you're over-estimating what can be tracked. Keeping your OS up-to-date is the only way to benefit from security patches and new features, like restricting tracking. An update does not normally alter any user settings, so again that's not a reason for not updating. Staying on an old version leaves you vulnerable to exploits, which is a much greater threat than normal browsing. I will update my answer.

Comment: @DaveN You still haven't said what OS you're running.

Comment: Thanks benwiggy, very useful information. It sounds like my plan will work to satisfaction. That is, on my mac on 10.12.6 I'll go rarely online and keep my private info/files. On my refurb mac, will keep it generally up to date and have an Admin account for boring regular stuff with all protections in place, and a Standard account in which to run dodgy stuff like Chrome and google search/mail/voice and let them track... almost no activity.

Comment: Apple updates are a topic for another thread, but based on actual personal experience with macos, ios, ipados, I guarantee you updates do make changes to user settings, and add new 'features' selected on by default, and hide them. I have about 8 or 9 Apple devices in regular use and it is really a pain and waste of time to chase thru every level of every setting and turn stuff off after every update. This blather about 'update to be secure but we're not telling you the details' is fear mongering by Apple, only small % truth/risk to average user imho.

Comment: @DaveN Security vulnerabilities and their fixes are well documented. https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-49/Apple.html I still think you're assuming all kinds of things that aren't actually the case.